# Avoid children rerendering when passing a function in props

Tags: reactjs

I have this parent component:

```
const MeasuresList: React.FC = () => {
    const root = useAppSelector(state => state.tree.root)
    const selected = useAppSelector(state => state.stats.selected)
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
    const {data, isFetching} = useGetMeasuresQuery(
        (root ? root.element.code : skipToken),
    )

    if (!data || isFetching)
        return null


    return <List dense disablePadding>
        {data.map(measure => {
            const isSelected = selected.indexOf(measure.code) !== -1

            return <MeasureSelectable
                key={measure.code}
                measure={measure}
                selected={isSelected}
                onChanged={() => dispatch(!isSelected ? addMeasure(measure.code) : removeMeasure(measure.code))}
            />
        })}
    </List>
}
```

which renders a list of:

```
const MeasureSelectable: React.FC<{
    measure: Measure,
    selected: boolean,
    onChanged: () => void,
}> = ({measure, selected, onChanged}) => {

    return <ListItem disablePadding>
        <ListItemButton dense disableGutters onClick={onChanged}>
            <ListItemIcon>
                <Checkbox
                    edge="start"
                    checked={selected}
                    disableRipple
                />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={measure.name}/>
        </ListItemButton>
    </ListItem>
}
```

The problem is that when I click on a checkbox on any child, the redux state changes (OK), the parent component gets rerendered (OK) but then every child gets rerendered because the function `() => dispatch(...)` is recreated each time causing the children rerendering, which is slow.

I would like that the function `() => dispatch(...)` is fixed (i.e. with useCallback, but I don't know how to use it since it has parameters which depend on each child), so that only the child with `selected` changed gets rerendered.

How could I do that? I cannot use `useCallback` inside the `onChanged`, I may define it at the beginning of the FC but then I'm not sure how to parametrize it (there should be a callbacked function for each key, so to speak)

Comment: Hey, I think this is a use case for the React.useMemo hook. [Try reading some docs about it.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)

Comment: Thanks, however I can't understand how to apply it in case of loops

Answer (score 0):

You may expose `measure` in `onChanged` callback from MeasureSelectable like this:
`onChanged: (measure: Measure) => void` and then use it in memoized function (the `useCallback` one) to determine if given element should be selected or not.

This way there will be only one instance of this function and props of `MeasureSelectable` will stay stable all the time.

Comment: But isn't that somehow redundant? The child already receives the `measure` in props, it seems redundant to me that it calls `onChanged` passing back the same props it got, I'm not sure...